# Taylor series convergence for $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Consider the Taylor series for $e^{-1/x^2}$ around $0$:

$$e^{-1/x^2}=1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{2!x^4}-\dfrac{1}{3!x^6}+\ldots$$

For which $x$ does the series on the right converge to $e^{-1/x^2}$?

Comment: This is the Laurent series, not Taylor's.

Comment: @JJ Beck : if you wanted a Taylor series for $f(x) \equiv e^{-1/x^2}$ wiht center zero, you'd have to define $f(0)=0$ because you can't divide by zero.  The Taylor series with center $0$ (that is, the Maclaurin series) turns out to be identically zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For which $y$ does $e^y = 1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!} + ...$ converge? Set $-\frac{1}{x^2} = y$ and you can find the corresponding values of $x$ which allows your expansion to converge.