# Can the remainder of a Taylor expansion be estimated from the coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, estimation, approximation-theory

Given a formula for the coefficients $c_n\in\mathbb C$ of a not analytically known function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C, z\mapsto f(z)$'s Taylor series, is there any way to estimate the remainder term of the order $N$

$$r_N(z) := f(z) - \sum_{n=0}^N c_n z^n$$

within a given radius $|z|\le\rho$ (truly smaller than the convergence radius) that only depends on a finite amount of the $c_n$ or some limit thereof? In other words, is there a way to obtain a $R_N$ such that $|r_n(z)|\le R_n(\rho)\ \forall |z|\le\rho$?

Comment: No, it can't. Remember the (in)famous example $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$: all coefficients of the Taylor series around $x=0$ are zero, and the remainder _is_ small for small $x$, but it can't be estimated from the coefficients.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Silly me, always forgetting to mention what Physicists implicitly assume, e.g. actual convergence and absence of singularities...

Comment: Sorry, but my $f(x)$ is in no way singular as a real function, we know a formula for the coefficients ($c_n=0$) , the series actually converges (to $0$), and since we assumed we don't know $f(x)$ analytically, we don't even know the series converges to another value.

Comment: Generally still no, because the relevant derivative participating in the remainder can still grow considerably away from the point of expansion. Remember these qualitatively bad examples are always close to qualitatively good examples in some sense. Somehow you really want your functions to be *quantitatively* good which usually means they are not too big in some Sobolev norm. Merely being qualitatively good is not as useful as we are sometimes led to believe.

Comment: @ProfessorVector $\exp(-1/x^2)$ has a [Laurent series with only negative coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1246380/163), I'm talking about (locally) entire functions that _do_ have an actually convergent Taylor series.

Comment: @Ian Agreed - I edited to clarify that I'm talking about (locally) holomorphic functions

Comment: Again you have the same problem especially as you move towards the boundary of the disk of convergence (if there is one).

Comment: Well, in that case, you'd be well advised to include somewhere in your question that $z$ is a _complex_ variable, and that the series has some (known?) positive radius of convergence. That radius also gives you the asymptotic behavior of the remainder, but hardly a rigorous estimate.

Comment: I still have difficulty understanding this question.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I was afraid so, my question seems to require optimization... Maybe [my attempted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2464891/163) clarifies this better

Comment: @ProfessorVector I tried improving the question and [give a rough estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2464891/163) but I'm sure that can be surpassed...

Comment: @Ian That's certain, but the question is what about regions "deeply" within the convergence ring?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to depend strongly upon what knowledge made you conclude that the radius of convergence is at least $\rho$? If for example, you happen to know that the function is analytic on a disk $D(0,\rho)$ and is uniformly bounded on that disk, say $|f(z)|\leq M<+\infty$ for all $|z|<\rho$ then indeed you can estimate the remainder. From Cauchy, integrating over a circle of radius $\rho-\epsilon$ and for $|z|<\rho$:
$$ f(z) = \oint_{\partial B} \frac{f(u)}{u-z}\frac{du}{2\pi i}
= \oint_{\partial B} \frac{f(u)}{u} \left( 1+ \frac{z}{u} + \cdots \right) \frac{du}{2\pi i}=\sum_{n=0}^{N} c_nz^n + R_N(z) $$
where (after taking the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$):
$$ |R_N(z)| \leq \left|\oint_{\partial B} \frac{f(u)}{u} \frac{z^{N+1}}{u^{N+1}}\frac{1}{u-z}  \frac{du}{2\pi i}\right| \leq M \left(\frac{|z|}{\rho}\right)^{N+1} \frac{1}{\rho-|z|}$$
Without any uniform bounds on $|f|$ (or the sequence $c_n$), I don't have any reasonable suggestion. After all you may always add $10^{266} z^{N+1}$ without changing the radius of convergence.

Comment: Thank you, that's an interesting approach. Of course by adding $10^{266}z^{N+1}$, you'd increase $M$ by up to $10^{266}\rho^{N+1}$ as well. Maybe a restriction to $c_n$ that are related via a finite analytical equation (e.g. a recurrence equation) would help here, since then such an irregular additional term would be excluded

Comment: A recurrence relation for $f$ indeed helps. But often by reducing to the above estimate. For example, counting binary trees you wind up looking at a generating fct $f$ for which: $f(z)=1+zf(z)^2$ and you may show that for $|z|\leq \rho<1/4$ there is $M=M(\rho)<+\infty$ for which my suggested estimate holds, and it gives result pretty close to the real ones. When recurrence is in the coeffs $c_n$ there are undoubtedly similar estimates, but I don't have any (natural) example.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give this a shot, also to clarify the question and hopefully attract better answers...

The convergence radius $R$ is given by

$$\frac 1R = \limsup_{n\to\infty} |c_n|^{\frac1n}.$$

Therefore,

$$\forall N\in\mathbb N\,\exists \epsilon_N>0\forall n>N:|c_n|^{\frac1n} < \frac{1+\epsilon_N}R \tag{*}\label{*}$$

(and $\epsilon_{n>N}\le\epsilon_N$ and $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\epsilon_N = 0$).

Thus for $|z|<R/(1+\epsilon_N)$,

$$\begin{align*}
  |r_{N-1}(z)| &= \Bigg|\sum_{n=N}^\infty c_n z^n\Bigg|
\\ &\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty |c_n|\cdot |z|^n
\\ &\stackrel{\eqref{*}}< \sum_{n=N}^\infty \underbrace{(1+\epsilon_N)^n \left|\frac zR\right|^n}_{=:(\zeta_N)^n} \tag{#}\label{#}
\\ &= \frac{(\zeta_N)^N}{1-\zeta_N}
< \frac{R}{R-(1+\epsilon_N)|z|}
\end{align*}$$

The final inequality is probably too generous... Note that $\eqref{#}$ converges due to $|z|<R/(1+\epsilon_N) \Leftrightarrow \zeta_N<1$. The same procedure can probably be applied to estimate the remainder of a Laurent series' principal part using $r = \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|c_{-n}|^{\frac1n}$.

It's probably not a spectacular boundary, so I hope someone else knows a better one...