# Series expansion of function with 0/0 behaviour near origin

Tags: limits, power-series

I am interested in the behaviour of
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}exp \left [-a \left ( \frac{b-x}{x} \right)^2 \right ]$$
near $x=0$. Evidently $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$,
because the $x$-denominator in the argument of the exponential will cause $f$ to decrease very rapidly with decreasing $|x|$. An expansion, or even
limit calculation, would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

We have that assuming $a>0$

$$e^{\left [-a \left ( \frac{b-x}{x} \right)^2 \right ]}=e^{-\frac{ab^2}{x^2}}e^{\frac{2ab}{x}}e^{-a}\sim e^{-\frac{ab^2}{x^2}}$$

therefore

$$f(x)\sim \frac1x e^{-\frac{ab^2}{x^2}} \to 0$$

indeed wlog $x>0$ by $y=\frac1x$

$$\frac1x e^{-\frac{ab^2}{x^2}}=\frac{y}{e^{ab^2y^2}}\to 0$$

Comment: Thank you, that is useful. Any ideas about the polynomial behaviour of $f(x)$ near $x=0$?

Comment: @J.Webb Your welcome! What polynomial are you interested in?

Comment: Something like a Taylor expansion.

Comment: We can proceed how indicated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246136/505767).

Comment: The series expansion you referred me to diverges as $x \rightarrow 0$ so is not useful for very small $x$.