# Radius of convergence of a non-zero function with zero Taylor series

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, germs

A classic example of a nonzero function with identically zero Taylor expansion is the following:

\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\quad &\text{if $x\neq 0$}\\
    0\quad &\text{if $x=0$}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
according to this post [Maclaurin series expansion for $e^{-1/x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246136/maclaurin-series-expansion-for-e-1-x2),
it is clear that the Taylor series is null, however I want to know what the radius of convergence is, I know that it is convergent in the neighborhood of zero, however using the definition

\begin{equation}
\alpha=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_{n}|},\quad R=\frac{1}{\alpha}
\end{equation}
I think that the radius of convergence is zero, however I don't know how to justify it, which help is well received

Comment: All the coefficients are zero, so the radius of convergence is infinite ($\alpha=0$ so by convention, $R=\infty$). Now, just because the Taylor series has infinite radius of convergence, doesn't mean the function it sums to (in this case $0$) is equal to the function you started with (namely $f$).

Answer (score 2):

The series itself is convergent everywhere, since $\alpha = 0$, by convention $ R = \infty$. This, however, does not mean that the series converges to the function from which you computed those coefficients - you need to prove that separately. The function you are talking about is not analytic at $x=0$, meaning it cannot be expressed as a Taylor series about that point.